# select data from related tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a table structure. table 2 has many to one relation with table 1. table 3 has many to one relation with table 2.

```
table 1 -> id_1, data

table 2 -> id_2, data, id_1 

table 3 - > id_3, data, filter, id_2
```

I want to select all data from table 1, where table 3's filter != 'abc';

I am not sure if I expressed my question correctly, also the title of the question is a bit vague(please help me correct it).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a join:

```
select a.*
from table1 a join table2 b on b.id_1 = a.id_1
              join table3 c on c.id_2 = b.id_2
where c.filter <> 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want match the rows in `table1` where there does not exist a corresponding row in `table3` where `filter = 'abc'` then you can use `NOT EXISTS` and joins across the bridging table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   table2 t2
                INNER JOIN table3 t3
                ON (t2.id_2 = t2.id_2)
         WHERE  t1.id_1 = t2.id_1
         AND    t2.filter = 'abc'
       );
```